# Warning: printf(): Too few arguments in helpers.php file

Tags: php, theme-development, themes, child-theme

So I'm getting the following error `Warning: printf(): Too few arguments in /lib/helpers.php on line 34`

So line 34 is `'class' => []`

```
// Define the read more url
function read_more_url() {

    // Grab the posts link and title
    echo '<a href="' . esc_url(get_the_permalink()) . '" title="' . the_title_attribute(['echo' => false]) . '">';

    printf(
        // Filters text content and strips out disallowed HTML
        wp_kses(
            __('Read more <span class="u-screen-reader-text">about %s</span>', 'Sema'),
            [
                'span' => [
                    'class' => []
                ]
            ]
        )
    );
}
```

Could someone tell me what I might be doing wrong? The echo is working correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `printf` statement awaits additional string argument which would be substituted instead of `%s`:

```
    printf(
        // Filters text content and strips out disallowed HTML
        wp_kses(
            __('Read more <span class="u-screen-reader-text">about %s</span>', 'Sema'),
            [
                'span' => [
                    'class' => []
                ]
            ]
        ), "some subject"
    );
```

This example would produce the following output:

`Read more <span class="u-screen-reader-text">about some subject</span>`

Comment: Ivan thanks so much! Is there a reason that my %s might not be returning `the_title()`?

Comment: It isn't supposed to return a title. It is supposed to be substituted by some string given as second `printf` parameter (use `the_title()` as second parameter for your case). The reason to use this technique is because you don't know how this phrase would be looking in some other language and where the post title should be appeared (at the beginning of the phrase, at the end of the phrase, etc).

Comment: Ahh, that makes much more sense! Would you tackle the print out any differently? I'm still in the learning phases and printf made the most sense to me - Now when I pass `get_title()` as the second param, of course like you mentioned, the output is `Hello World!Read more about`.

Comment: Try `the_title('', '', false)` instead. Or better use `get_the_title()`.

Comment: Works like a charm! Appreciate all the help!